# Migrate django app to multiple servers

Tags: python, django, fabric

I'd like to migrate a django app to multiple hosts with a fabfile. The problem is all hosts connects to same database (in another server) and `migrate` command runs for each host.

I may select one host as master and run migrate command only from master but wonder if there is more elegant and proper solution for this.

**fabfile.py**

```
def migrate():
    virtualenv('python manage.py makemigrations')
    virtualenv('python manage.py migrate')

def prod():
    env.user = 'myuser'
    env.hosts = ['X1', 'X2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have about three options.

There is a `@runs_once` decorator you can use. Documented [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.runs_once). Where you'd just do something like:

```
@runs_once
def migrate():
    virtualenv('python manage.py makemigrations')
    virtualenv('python manage.py migrate')

def prod():
    env.user = 'myuser'
    env.hosts = ['X1', 'X2']``
```

Called like:

```
$ fab -R myRole migrate update
```

You can also just apply specific roles to use on said tasks which is shown [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute):

```
from fabric.api import run, roles

env.roledefs = {
    'db': ['db1'],
    'web': ['web1', 'web2', 'web3'],
}

@roles('db')
def migrate():
    # Database stuff here.
    pass

@roles('web')
def update():
    # Code updates here.
    pass
```

Called like:

```
$ fab migrate update
```

And if you'd like to get more fine grained those same functions can be coupled with the [execute()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) function (as is shown in that section's docs) and make a `deploy` function that calls those other tasks for you. Looking like this:

```
def deploy():
    execute(migrate)
    execute(update)
```

Called like:

```
 $ fab deploy
```

Comment: @run_once is a great anwser. Thanks